# How to select rows in pandas based on a condition with a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':y}) #dataframe to work with
```

which, plotted using matplotlib scatter looks like this.[image]
I would like to select the bottom three points using Pandas, **without iterating over the rows of my dataframe** (because of speed considerations of a large dataframe), and without simply selecting 1st, 4th and 7th point of the dataframe:
[image: fig2]

I tried selecting based on a condition:

```
selected_df = df.loc[df["y"] <=3] #selects an extra point at x=1,y=2
```

This selects an extra point which I don't want. I also tried building two lists of values representing a line that separates the bottom points from others:

```
x_line = [1,2,3]
y_line = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
```

[image: fig3]

```
selected_df = df.loc[df["y"] <=y_line ] #y_line is a list, doesn't work
```

I also unfortunately must not solve it by filling `y_line` with more points to make `y_line` same size as `df["y"]`.
Can anyone please show me the direction how to select the bottom points preferably using functions of DataFrame such as `df.where` or a condition? I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: `df.sort_values(['x','y']).drop_duplicates('x')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, what you're esentially looking for is the lowest `y` for each `x`, so you can phrase this as a `groupby` problem:

```
>>> selected_df = df.groupby("x", as_index=False).y.min()
>>> selected_df

   x  y
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  3  3
```